# Make [hapijs] a synonym of [hapi.js] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

- [hapijs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hapijs) tag => 1254 questions / 546 watchers
- [hapi.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hapi.js) tag => 51 questions / 23 watchers

Both relate to the same Node.js framework: https://hapi.dev/

**Proposal:**
Make [hapijs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hapijs) a synonym of [hapi.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hapi.js). (I currently lack the reputation in the tag to suggest this myself.)

**Notes:**

- Making [hapi.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hapi.js) the main tag would align with [node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js), [vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue.js), ... naming convention.
- The tag description of [hapijs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hapijs) being slightly more descriptive might be favored during the merge operation, would it be approved.

Comment: I'd ask to remove the `hapijs` tag. In Dutch language, it's a bite of ice cream :-)